# TFS and SVN

Tags: svn, tfs

I'm about to begin working on a collaborative effort with another vendor. The vendor has the source code and an SVN repository, while we have TFS. I'm interesting in using the Work Item tracking available in TFS but use SVN as the source control. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Another option I think would be to have some kind of polling mechanism so that I could download SVN source in to TFS source and then just use TFS source control as I would regularly. I think the main problem there would be getting my changes back in to the SVN repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it's possible, but you'll have no way to associate work items with changesets or shelvesets, which to me is one of the things I love most about TFS.

I think either way you're going to have some tricky merging/synchronizing to do.  In my opinion, your best bet is to agree on a single source control solution for both teams.

If you *only* want to use TFS's work item tracking without it's source control functionality, you should be able to.

Comment: Yes, I agree... and I thought about that, which is why maybe I was thinking about the polling thing, then our people could see work item progress then we'd still need to somehow communicate that back to there people, which I guess I can leave up to the project manager.

Comment: Trying to keep two repositries in sync of *any* two VC systems is just opening yourself up to a whole world of hurt.  I personally agree with the answer that you are best of picking one solution that both parties like and use it.  That said - no reason that you cannot use TFS just for Work Items if you already have it installed but you'll obviously miss the integration with Version Control.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just thought of a work around. I should be able to download there source to a vendor-src dir... copy that too our trunk then check that into tfs...

To do a merge, get latest from vendor svn... use Beyond Compare to merge our trunk and vendor-src and with beyond compare i can associate both folders with there respective version control repos.

Kind of clunky and some disconnect because both sides will be missing check-in comments, and not really optimal, but I believe it to be the best option I have available right now.

Comment: If you really wanted to clunk something together you could take a look at the TFS Migration and Sync framework on CodePlex to automate all this stuff.  But like I say - you are probably heading for a world of pain and should just use one repository unless there is a lack of connectivity between you.